# jquery - issue with appendTo method and possibly messing up z-index of the DIV being appended

Tags: jquery, css

Please help me with below issue if you have seen it happening before, have been struggling for quite some time.
I have below code that appends a DIV to a different DIV based on some action and then toggle the display to visible.

```
$(".personalizeflyout").prependTo("#personalizemenuitem");
$(".personalizeflyout").show();
```

After I show the DIV I am placing an iFrame at exact same coordinates as the personalizeflyout DIV with same width and height. Code below:

```
$(".personalizeflyout").iFrameShim();
jQuery.fn.iFrameShim = function() {
    var o = $(this[0]);
    $(".iFrameShimmer").attr("height",o.height());
    $(".iFrameShimmer").attr("width",o.width());
    $(".iFrameShimmer").css("top",o.offset().top);
    $(".iFrameShimmer").css("left",o.offset().left);
}
```

This is the CSS for personalizeflyout (notice z-index 10)

```
.personalizeflyout {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 7px 0 0 0;
width:434px;
position: absolute;
z-index:10;
display:none;
}
```

And then I have iFrame with below CSS.

```
.iFrameShimmer {
position:absolute;
top: 400;
left: 200;
z-index:1;
}
```

Issue Description:
The z-index of DIV seems to be getting messed up when I use the above code.
But if I don't use the appendTo and run the rest of the code, i.e. toggling display to show and placing iFrame with same dimension and location attributes, the DIV is properly overlayed on top of the iFrame. I am trying various things but no clue yet why the appendTo or prependTo  methods to attach DIV is causing the problem. I tested with FireBug and the z-index is shown as what I set.
I have also explicitly set the DIV and iFrame z-Index after all the code in the iFrameShim method and that doesnt seem to have made any difference.

I also tested this in version 1.6.4 and the issues exists. BTW I am using version 1.3.x

Answer (score 1):

Z-index is only applied when the parent element has a position set position. So, if #personalizemenuitem does not have a position specified in CSS, the browser won't respect the z-index you are trying to set for .personalizeflyout and .iFrameShimmer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. #personalizemenuitem already has position attribute set. However I applied position attribute to all its parent elements up to body and that didn't make any difference. Wondering if you can suggest me to check anything else...
Thanks,